# readHTMLTable is not giving me the information I want

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to analyze some Formule 1 data. Wikipedia has a table with the data I want. I am importing the data into R with the code below:

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)

url    <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Formula_One_drivers"
tabs   <- getURL(url)
tabs   <- readHTMLTable(tabs, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
pilots <- tabs[[3]]
pilots <- pilots[-dim(pilots)[1], ]

head(pilots[, 1])
[1] "Abate, CarloCarlo Abate"
[2] "Abecassis, GeorgeGeorge Abecassis"
[3] "Acheson, KennyKenny Acheson"
[4] "Adamich, Andrea deAndrea de Adamich"
[5] "Adams, PhilippePhilippe Adams"
[6] "Ader, WaltWalt Ader"
```

However, the pilot names are strange. Notice how they are. I'd like them to be like this:

```
head(pilots[, 1])
[1] "Carlo Abate"
[2] "George Abecassis"
[3] "Kenny Acheson"
[4] "Andrea de Adamich"
[5] "Philippe Adams"
[6] "Walt Ader"
```

However, it seems I am not able to write a regex that can deal with this problem or find an argument for the function `readHTMLTable` that ignores the sortkey value in the table I am interested. How can I solve my problem?

Comment: Use `readHTMLTable` with a bespoke `elFun` argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `readHTMLTable` with a bespoke `elFun` argument.

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)

url    <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Formula_One_drivers"
tabs   <- getURL(url)
myFun <- function(x){
  if(length(y <- getNodeSet(x, ".//a")) > 0){
    # return data.frame
    title <-  xpathSApply(x, ".//a", fun = xmlGetAttr, name = "title")
    href <-  xpathSApply(x, ".//a", fun = xmlGetAttr, name = "href")
    value <-  xpathSApply(x, ".//a", fun = xmlValue)
    return(paste(value, collapse = ","))
  }
  xmlValue(x, encoding = "UTF-8")
}
tabs   <- readHTMLTable(tabs, elFun = myFun, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
pilots <- tabs[[3]]
pilots <- pilots[-dim(pilots)[1], ]

> head(pilots[, 1])
[1] "Carlo Abate"       "George Abecassis"  "Kenny Acheson"     "Andrea de Adamich"
[5] "Philippe Adams"    "Walt Ader"   

> pilots[1,]
         Name Country   Seasons Championships Entries Starts Poles Wins Podiums Fastest laps Points[note]
1 Carlo Abate   Italy 1962,1963             0       2      0     0    0       0            0            0
```

Comment: What is the issue with the values in that column please - why are the other columns read in okay, but not these

Comment: `readHTMLTable` applies the `xmlValue` function to each `td` node it finds. This results in values being concatenated when a `td` node has children. By default `elFun = xmlValue`.